# Provided Maven Coordinates must be in the form 'groupId:artifactId:version' PySpark and Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

While converting Kafka messages to dataframe am getting error while passing the packages as an argument.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0.jar: org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11:jar:2.1.1 pyspark-shell'pyspark-shell'

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)

df = spark \
  .read \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "Jim_Topic") \
  .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

> Error
>           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11;2.2.0.jar: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the exception suggests, you have a typo in one of your dependencies.

---

```
org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:jar:
```

is missing the version (and it also has an unecessary `:`). The following should do the trick:

```
org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0
```

---

The full dependencies will become:

```
'--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11:2.1.1'
```

Comment: Thank you. Still am getting same error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Provided Maven Coordinates must be in the form 'groupId:artifactId:version'. The coordinate provided is: org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12.jar:
 at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)`

Comment: @JimMacaulay My bad. Edited my answer.

Comment: Its still the same. I used `os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0.jar:,spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.3.1.jar pyspark-shell'`  Am getting same error

Comment: @JimMacaulay What is the error? Also, remove the `,` between the two dependencies.

Comment: Also i tried adding the jars alone. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62347453/pyspark-kafka-py4j-protocol-py4jjavaerror-an-error-occurred-while-calling-o28-l` it pop ups new error

Comment: I removed , . Not i got new error - UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES , org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11;2.2.0.jar: not found. Edited the error in the question

Comment: @JimMacaulay Mate I cannot help you. Everytime you return back with random characters added to your dependencies. Stop trial and error and try to understand what you are doing.

Comment: I understand. Since am new am struggling little. As you said, i removed ,. `os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0.jar: org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11:jar:2.1.1 pyspark-shell'`  But not sure about `UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES` error

Comment: @JimMacaulay The error mentions `org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11;2.2.0.jar:`. Why did you add a `;` instead of `:` ?

Comment: No, i did not add it. Posted the code. Is it may be because am defining two dependencies together?

Comment: @JimMacaulay I updated the string. Try it and let me know

Comment: Now the error is Error: Missing application resource.

Comment: Complete error is `Error: Missing application resource.

Usage: spark-submit [options] <app jar | python file | R file> [app arguments]
Usage: spark-submit --kill [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
Usage: spark-submit --status [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
Usage: spark-submit run-example [options] example-class [example args]`

Comment: @JimMacaulay Okay, this issue has been fixed. Please ask a different question because we already added tons of comments here.

Comment: Sure will ask a question and let you know

Comment: I have asked a new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62348338/pyspark-kafka-error-missing-application-resource, kindly help me on this