# PySpark Kafka py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.load

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

While converting Kafka messages to dataframe am getting error while passing the packages as an argument.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.0.2.jar,spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.3.1.jar pyspark-shell'

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)

df = spark \
  .read \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "Jim_Topic") \
  .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.load.
>   : java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider could not be instantiated

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the version of `spark-sql-kafka` does not match the spark version you are currently running.

---

For example, the dependency you are currently using would work for Spark 2.4.1:

```
org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.1
```

To fix the issue, simply use the version of your Spark at the end of the dependency string (replace `x.y.z`):

```
org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:x.y.z
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining the jars with below configuration helped me,

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
  .appName("Kafka Spark")\
  .config("spark.jars", "/C:/Hadoop/Spark/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin- hadoop2.7/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar")\
  .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/C:/Hadoop/Spark/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar")\
  .config("spark.executor.extraLibrary", "/C:/Hadoop/Spark/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar")\
  .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/C:/Hadoop/Spark/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar")\
  .getOrCreate()
```