# PySpark Kafka Error: Missing application resource

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

Below error is triggered when i added the below dependency to the code,

```
'--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11:2.1.1'
```

Below is the code,

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11:2.1.1'


sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)

df = spark \
  .read \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "Jim_Topic") \
  .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

Below is the error,

> Error: Missing application resource.
>
> Usage: spark-submit [options]  [app arguments]
>   Usage: spark-submit --kill [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
>   Usage: spark-submit --status [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
>   Usage: spark-submit run-example [options] example-class [example args]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to provide the name of your python file.

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11:2.1.1 your_python_file.py'
```

---

Alternatively, a nicer way would be:

```
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.jars", "/path/to/your/jar")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Comment: I use your alternate wayby providing the path to the jars. Am getting below error `To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
20/06/12 22:32:17 ERROR SparkContext: Failed to add /C:/Hadoop/Spark/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/ to Spark environment
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Directory C:\Hadoop\Spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\bin is not allowed for addJar`